# Icacls Grant all users access to a folder including new files?

Tags: batch, batch-file, shared-folders, icacls

I use the following command (in an admin batch file) to grant all users (specifically users on the network) full access to a folder and all its contents:

```
Icacls %fold% /grant Everyone:F /inheritance:e /T
```

However, it is not applying these settings to files newly created. What am I missing in the Icacls command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're enabling inheritance for this item separately from its ACL entries. This means it will *receive* ACEs from its parent. It has absolutely **nothing to do** with whether it'll give its own custom ACEs to be inherited by children.

You have to mark *each* ACL entry as inheritable, separately for child files (object inherit) and child folders (container inherit):

```
icacls foo /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F
```

This is equivalent to the "Inherit: [Files and subfolders]" drop-down in *Properties – Security – Advanced*.

When you add ACEs marked inheritable, icacls will propagate them automatically and the `/T` option is unnecessary (maybe even slightly harmful).

Comment: Tip: First use `takeown` then `icacls`. `Everyone` can be replaced with current user name.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Why would you do that? OP specifically wants to grant access to _all users_, not just to themselves.

Comment: question, what do I put in the place of `foo`? Or is that what I should have there?

Comment: @MarkDodsons `foo` will be replaced by `%fold%`... it's just the folder path.

Comment: thanks. Does foo usually refer to the folder or file in question?

Comment: It is a commonly used [placeholder word](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name#Computing). Just like your `%Fold%` in your own example, it refers to whatever it needs to refer at the given moment, and you're expected to substitute it with the real thing, be it a file or something else.